# Is using 'decltype' in the declaration of pointer to member valid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member, decltype

Imagine for some strange reason I write this:

```
int main()
{
    struct S
    {        
        int i;
    } var;


    int decltype(var)::* pint = &decltype(var)::i;
}
```

[GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L8Yyiofi3IjoALEE) seems to compile it fine although [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DzztvqwWG1AVRrUK) fails with some indeterminate syntax-related error message.

So what does the holy ISO paper says about this - is this valid or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a [known bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20990) in Clang.

The code is valid.

N4140 [dcl.mptr]/1:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> *nested-name-specifier* `*` *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> `D1`*
>
> and the *nested-name-specifier* denotes a class, and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list `T`*”, then the type of the identifier of `D` is “*derived-declarator-type-list cv-qualifier-seq* pointer
>   to member of class nested-name-specifier of type `T`”. The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* (7.6.1) appertains to
>   the pointer-to-member.

In this definition we are interested in *nested-name-specifier*, and it's defined at [expr.prim.general]/8 as (emphasis mine):

> *nested-name-specifier:*
>
> *`::`
>   type-name `::`
>
>   namespace-name `::`
>
>   **decltype-specifier `::`**
>
>   nested-name-specifier identifier `::`
>
>   nested-name-specifier `template`<sub>opt</sub> simple-template-id `::`*